# Progress Bar in Action Bar: Make width fill screenwidth

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-progressbar

[image: screenshot]

I have a progress bar in my action bar, which is set to `indeterminate`. As you can see in my screenshot my progress bar's width is not 100% of the screen width. it has a margin on both sides. I am using the support libraries and actionbar activity. Is i possible to make it's width to 100% screen width? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

what are you looking for is an image of progress bar with different **padding** ...

see [this](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html) ... select an **progress bar** icon from clipart a set different padding for image ... you can see what is padding doing with an image on example at the botton of the page :) this will 100% help you ...

Comment: There is no padding in the ProgressBar primary progress 9 patch bitmap. Both in the bitmap or in the style.

Comment: Did you read the link that ive posted ? I was talking about padding bar when you choose an image from  **android asset studio**

Comment: Yes. But that padding only applies to the ActionBar icons and not to the indeterminate progress bar. I've checked my generated resources, and the image that is used in the ProgressBar for the horizontal indeterminate (and also for the non-indeterminate) horizontal progress, has no padding whatsoever. I've also checked the generated style in XML, and it has no padding also.